# How to get the get the lowest sum of 3 elements in matrix

Tags: python, matrix, zip

```
A = [[1, 2, 4], 
        [3, 5, 6],
        [7,8,9]]


def sumof(A,3):
```

We need to find the lowest sum of 3 elements
here `1 + 2 + 3 = 6` so output is `(1,2,3)`

Can we do by using zip

Comment: This is fairly simple using numpy, have you given it a try?

Comment: convert to 1D list, sort it and get first three elements (they will have the smallest value) and sum them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one basic solution, convert nested list into flat list, sort it,slice sorted list and sum:

```
A = [[1, 2, 4],
        [3, 5, 6],
        [7,8,9]]


def sumof(A, n):
    # convert nested list into flat list 
    flat_list = [item for sublist in A for item in sublist]
    return sum(sorted(flat_list)[:n])

print (sumof(A,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large array, you can do this without sorting the list, 
which is a little faster like

```py
from operator import add
from functools import reduce

A = [[1, 2, 4],
     [3, 5, 6],
     [7,8,9]]

addlists = lambda l: reduce(add, l)
list_A = addlists(A)
result = [list_A.pop(list_A.index(min(list_A))) for _ in range(3)]
```

It's a little more complicated, though the modules imported are really useful.